# How to use inject Java EE Event into EJB when deployed in an EAR?

Tags: java, events, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.0

I'm having an issue with Injecting a javax.enterprise.event.Event instance into my EJB.  The inject of the event works fine when the EJB is used in a web app deployed in a war, but when i deploy the web app in large application inside an EAR the event is null.  Does anyone why that might be and how i can use inject the event when i deploy as an EAR?  I'm using JBoss as 7.1.

Thank you.

Comment: The was an issue related to this here : https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1458.  Adding bean.xml to the ejb-jar seems to have worked.